# Asp.Net Mvc Angular js load ng-view with layout content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, ng-view

I have used the **Asp.net MVC 5 Razor** and **angularjs**.
Now my view have the layout .That layout contains top and side menu bar.
So when the view load i got nested page top and side bar in the ng-view.**How do i resolve this.**

> If i was tried with another one root view and removed the layout.that was
>   worked fine.but when i hit F5 loaded the action alone.Master content is missed

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
    <header ng-include="'/Partials/TopNavbar'" class="topnavbar-wrapper"></header>
    <!-- sidebar-->
    <aside ng-include="'/Partials/Sidebar'" ng-controller="SidebarController" class="aside"></aside>
    <!-- offsidebar-->
    <aside ng-include="'/Partials/Offsidebar'" class="offsidebar"></aside>
    <!-- Main section-->
    <section>
        <!-- Page content-->
        <div ui-view="" autoscroll="false" ng-class="app.viewAnimation" class="content-wrapper">
            Tested
            <div ui-view="" data-autoscroll="false" class="wrapper">
                @Styles.Render("~/bundles/bootstrapStyles")
                @Styles.Render("~/bundles/appStyles")
                @RenderBody()
                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/baseScripts")
                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/appScripts")
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Page footer-->
    <footer ng-include="'/Partials/Footer'"></footer>
```

**View**

```
@{
// This is requried for AngularJS because we have to send only the view markup (not within the layout)
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";}


<small>Subtitle</small>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
testing A blank template
    </div>
</div>
```

This view has refered the layout.
So while page load the Master content loaded perfectly.but when the ng-view load again the master content loaded like nested.

Comment: Some code would be wonderfull

Comment: I'm confused, you are using `ng-view` or `ui-view`? tag is `ng-view` & code says `ui-view`

Comment: Sorry,i have used the ui-view